# How can i restrict the Screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

i am working on a project where i have to create web desktop. when user click's on calendar or any icon new window pops up everything works fine. except that user can drag the new window outside the screen area as well. what I am doing, i create a dive windows in html and am inserting new window to windows (div) dynamically. So what will be easiest way to restrict the the window not to be dragged out side the screen?
thanks

Comment: use a modal window

Comment: use a modal *dialog*